# Java Web Framework

Tags: java, web-frameworks

Is there a Java Web Framework, with mvc, thrid-party integration APIs, libraries and tools? Something like Zend Framework for PHP?

Comment: My careful guess would be, there are dozens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Zend for a while, I found the transition to Spring fairly easy.
Spring does come with more bells and whistles (Dependancy injection, AOP etc)

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of Java web Frameworks, here you have a list with lots of them: http://java-source.net/open-source/web-frameworks

The most "famous" would be Struts, JSF or Spring mvc framework (not in that particular order).

Comment: I have worked with struts, its just a mvc, i was looking for something of a library kind of thing.

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean by "something of a library kind of thing". I use Struts and I have it integrated with Spring, Hibernate and many other tools, but I guess that is not what you meant. If you clarify that maybe I can suggest something more specific.

Comment: that is what i am talking about, in java we use, spring and struts and hibernate and many other tools, was just thinking aloud if there was one framework, which had all the things and others, like integration with facebook, youtube and etc., loosely coupled to form a complete library...

Answer (score 3):

[Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) is more light weight compared to Spring , JSF or Struts. More close to Zend in some sense. and has scala support :)

Answer (score 1):

You also have [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home)

> **AppFuse** is an open source project and
>   application that uses open source
>   tools built on the Java platform to
>   help you develop Web applications
>   quickly and efficiently. It was
>   originally developed to eliminate the
>   ramp-up time found when building new
>   web applications for customers. At its
>   core, AppFuse is a project skeleton,
>   similar to the one that's created by
>   your IDE when you click through a
>   wizard to create a new web project.
>
> AppFuse 2.x is a restructuring of
>   AppFuse 1.x to use Maven 2 and JDK 5
>   and annotations. The major reasons we
>   use Maven 2 are:
>
> ```
> Dependency downloading
> Easier maintenance (everything can be compiled at once)
> Easier upgrading for end-users
> ```
>
> If you'd like to help out or ask
>   questions about AppFuse 2.0, please do
>   so on the user mailing list. If you'd
>   like to use AppFuse 2.0, see the Demos
>   and Videos and use the QuickStart
>   Guide to get started.